# Why things in motion make noise?

Tags: acoustics, everyday-life, vibrations

In most of the cases on earth,the things in motion definitely make noise but things at rest do not.For example:-boiling water,a body falling down,a man walking on road,flowing water etc.

But the things at rest such as a body kept on ground,still water etc do not.Is motion necessary to produce sound on earth?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Sound is a direct product of motion or vibration. When something moves, it compresses the air in front of it (literally pushes the air), which creates a pressure wave that we interpret as air. Now its true that most things "vibrate" even while at rest, and as such can make noise if the oscillations are large enough, but for the most part, these oscillations either occur in such a high frequency that we can't detect them, or with such little intensity that we don't perceive them.

Comment: I agree, but just to add on, vibrations don't necessarily need to go through air. They can propagate through any substrate. Air is just what humans generally use to hear the vibrations of surrounding movements.

Comment: +1, but I think you meant to say "a pressure wave that we interpret as _sound_", not "air".